# AWS EB: Multiple env.config files for various environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, app-config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got an env.config in source control but pretty much the only things I can put in it are things that relate to all my various environments (production, staging). I've got environment specific settings that I want to add to the env.config file (for instance, the DB host) that will change from environment to environment. How can I handle these differences? Right now I'm doing it from the AWS console where I can manage it in the GUI on a per-environment basis, but I'd love to be able to change a lot of this stuff from git so I don't have to be logging into the console whenever I want to change something.

Is there any way to have multiple, environment specific config files?

Answer (score 2):

So this has been posted before in the AWS forums. (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=529373) So far there's only workarounds! The problem is that the .config files would require some logic to figure out what environment you're attempting to target. Personally I don't think any logic is required, as you could simply namespace the config settings based on the AWS environment name you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your usecase is similar to what is discussed in [How to configure Elastic Beanstalk for RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973083/how-to-configure-elastic-beanstalk-for-rds)

You may want to use 'eb branch'. You can then have multiple environments with different configurations.

More documentation on eb branch [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html)

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently using `eb branch` - it's just the trouble of having to switch branches in git to make changes that I'd like to avoid, but perhaps this isn't all that troubling with the right workflow. Thanks for the help - though I'm not sure I can mark it as *the* answer, although it is an answer that can work.